# Folding code in VIM

Tags: vim

I was trying to implement code folding in my VIM.
I believe the standard commands for them are  za, zc, zo etc.
As i understand, one doesn't need to do anything special to make these commands work. 
I am mainly a JS programmer.

However none of these commands are working in my VIM. I am using VIM 7.2

Below is my .vimrc file.
The reason I am presenting my entire .vimrc file is because I am guessing there might be an addon that I am using which might be causing the folding commands to not work.

If anyone has an idea what is amiss here.. kindly point out.

```
" Start pathogen plugins "
call pathogen#infect()

" Automatic syntax highlight on "
syntax on

" Necessary for NerdCommenter to Work "
filetype plugin indent on

set nocompatible
source $VIMRUNTIME/vimrc_example.vim

" Replace tabs with spaces "
set expandtab

" Make tab 2 space wide
set tabstop=2
set shiftwidth=2

" If I am in an indented block of code, keep the indentation level when I "
" press enter "
set autoindent

" Stop vim from creating automatic backups "
set nobackup
set noswapfile
set nowb
set nowritebackup

" Show line numbers "
set number

" Shift+Tab unindents a line "
imap <S-Tab> <Esc><<i
nmap <S-tab> <<

" Remove trailing spaces when saving a file "
autocmd BufWritePre * :%s/\s\+$//e

" Highlight all occurances of search "
set hlsearch

" Ignore case during search
set ignorecase

" Show tabs and trailing spaces "
set list listchars=tab:.\ ,trail:·

" set colorscheme "
colorscheme desert
set background=dark

set ff=unix
set showtabline=2
set smarttab
set incsearch

" Store a history of commands "
set history=1000

" Number of undo levels "
set undolevels=1000

" Change title of tab "
set title

" Open nerdtree plugin when vim starts "
let g:nerdtree_tabs_open_on_console_startup=1

au BufNewFile,BufRead *.less set filetype=less

let g:DirDiffExcludes = ".svn,*.swp"
let Grep_Skip_Dirs = '.svn'

" smart way to move between windows
map <C-j> <C-W>j
map <C-k> <C-W>k
map <C-h> <C-W>h
map <C-l> <C-W>l

" useful mappings for managing tabs
map <leader>tn :tabnew<cr>
map <leader>to :tabonly<cr>
map <leader>tc :tabclose<cr>
map <leader>tm :tabmove

set wrap linebreak nolist

nnoremap tp :tabprev<CR>
nnoremap tn :tabnext<CR>
nnoremap tf :tabfirst<CR>
nnoremap tl :tablast<CR>

highlight ExtraWhitespace ctermbg=red guibg=red
match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/
autocmd BufWinEnter * match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/
autocmd InsertEnter * match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+\%#\@<!$/
autocmd InsertLeave * match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/
autocmd BufWinLeave * call clearmatches()

function! TrimWhiteSpace()
    %s/\s\+$//e
endfunction
autocmd BufWritePre *.* :call TrimWhiteSpace()
```

Comment: open a js file, what is the output of `:set fdm?` ?

Comment: foldmethod was missing .. i set it to indent first.. not much help for javascript. I am now trying to incorporate syntax based folding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that for the folding commands to work, you'd need to set foldmethod option. The simplest one to start with would be 'indent', in my opinion.

Comment: Provide the code and explain why your proposition will solve the exposed problem

Answer (score 0):

I use:

```
vmap <F4> zf
vmap <F5> zd
```

in my .vimrc file. This allows me to use F4 and F5 keys to fold/unfold.